# What does this 'String.format("...");' in Java do?

Tags: java, string-formatting

```
String.format("%-" + 3 + "." + 3 + "s", givenString);
```

This is supposed to add white spaces but it doesn't. I tried it on an online compiler and it adds up the numbers to the string. I don't understand what that's doing. Could someone explain?

Comment: what givenString values have you tried?

Comment: Just a string. eg: "aa"

Comment: Have you looked at the javadoc of [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) and followed the links to more information? If so, what is unclear about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`public static String format(String format, Object... args)` - this is the method declaration.

```
String format = "%-" + 3 + '.' + 3 + 's';   // = %-3.3s
String.format(format, givenString);
```

This is used to build `format` dynamically, but it does not have variables in it, so you could replace it with `String.format("%-3.3s", givenString);`

According to format, this prints a **string** with a maximum of **3** characters in length. It reserves 3 symbols per line and it will be left justified in case givenString is less than 3 characters long.

**Demo:**

```
System.out.println(String.format("%-3.3s", "ab"));  // "ab "
System.out.println(String.format("%-3.3s", "abc"));  // "abc"
System.out.println(String.format("%-3.3s", "abcd"));  // "abc"
System.out.println(String.format("%-3.3s", "a") + String.format("%-3.3s", "b"));  // "a  b  "
```

See more in [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/)

Comment: It also left-justfies the string due to the `-3`